# python tool to create skeleton for PyPI package?

Tags: python, rubygems, pip, cpan, pypi

I want to write my first python package that I can upload to PyPi. 
My question is is there any tool to initialize the required skeleton for the PyPi package ? 
So far I have found instructions here http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html but it requires me to create all the files manually. I come from a Perl background and in Perl I could use following to create skeleton for cpan module.

```
module-starter --module=Foo::Bar --author="Foo Bar" --email=foo@bar.com
```

In ruby I could just do

```
 bundle gem foo::bar
```

I am surprised that there isn't anything similar in python or may be just I couldn't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one: [cookiecutter-pypackage](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage)

By the way, I think you should do it by hand at first so you can have a better understanding about how to creat a python package. When you're familiar with it, you can use tools to make this task automatically.

Further reading:

- The official package guide: [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/index.html)
- [Open Sourcing a Python Project the Right Way](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/)
- [Cookiecutter: Project Templates Made Easy](http://www.pydanny.com/cookie-project-templates-made-easy.html)

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I was looking for. I am still on Centos 6, python version 2.6  and unfortunately latest cookiecutter has removed support for this python version.  so I will need to get latest python version first. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Pylease**](https://github.com/bagrat/pylease), the `v0.3` was released just yesterday.

It works pretty simple:

```
$ mkdir your_project && cd your_project
$ pylease init your_project
```

This command creates the basic minimal stuff for a Python project:

- `setup.py` - with a call to the [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) `setup` method, supplying the name and the version of your project
- `setup.cfg` - with basic configuration for `Pylease`
- `your_project/__init__.py` - with the `__version__` variable defined in the module root

Furthermore you can extend it and customise to fit your needs. For more information [see the docs](https://github.com/bagrat/pylease#extensions).

Comment: Link does not work anymore

Comment: Thank you @Krishna, I've updated the links, though I haven't maintained the tool for years.